# Gmail cannot receive wordpress email

Tags: wordpress

I trying to send email to my `gmail`, but I cannot see the email in my `gmail`. I also tried to send the email to my `hotmail`, it is working when send to `hotmail`.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, email service providers are very string with spam. I think your mail that you sended with [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) is in your Gmail `spam` folder. You're maybe sending it from `localhost` or something like that. So Gmail put it by default to the spam folder. You can recover that by mapping a public domain name on your `smtp` server or like [@raman-kuman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5903965/raman-kumar)'s answer, you can use a plugin like [Postman SMTP plugin](https://tah.wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) to configure an email service like [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229) or [Hotmail](http://support.postbox-inc.com/hc/en-us/articles/202200090-Setting-Postbox-up-with-Windows-live-com-hotmail-com-and-outlook-com). If you use another famous email service, you can maybe find the settings [here](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-settings.html).

I would highly recommend you to use a personal mail server, so you can personalize your email like:

- `no-reply@my-awesome-domain.name` for a notification
- `contact@my-awesome-domain.name` for contact
- ...

It's looks better than `my-awesome-company@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely to do with :

1.) Your SMTP relaying settings within Wordpress. Check how it's configured and post a new question if you're struggling to get them to work. If your using a SMTP relay service then confirm these credentials are correct.

2.) The email address you are sending out as. If your sending as GMAIL or Hotmail e.g. administrator@hotmail.com from Wordpress using the PHP to send mail then it maybe be sending the mail from the IP address of your webserver which will not be part of the Hotmail/Gmails SPF record so recipient servers would block you on connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gmail's `SMTP` using [Postman SMTP plugin](https://tah.wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/), it works for all..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your email address that is sending from WordPress is the same as your domain name - something like wordpress@yourwebsite.com, otherwise use the Postman plugin, it will take a bit of configuration but you will be able to send to anywhere.